# powershell or net sending emails with authentication

Tags: .net, email, powershell

I'm using powershell cmdlet

```
send-mailmessage `
                    -SmtpServer 192.168.170.56 `
                    -to "<dex@dex.com>" `
                    -from "SFRBsendingScr <ms@pri.com>" `
                    -subject "(test) PRIMFRB transfer $date" `
                    -body "$teloadmin" -BodyAsHtml `
                    -ErrorAction Stop
```

for sending emails, but our smtp server (LotusNotes) require authentication to send emails out of our company. Ho can I add authentication, or is there another way to do it? Thank you

Comment: have you try the -credential parameter?

Comment: No, I found -credential parameter in PS documentation example, but it contains domain\name. I need to enter name and password..

Comment: I made the test with -credential parameter on one of my SMTP internet relay that use authentication and it works, but the SMTP server is a Microsoft one, so it probably accept one of the Microsoft Authentication supported by PSCredentials. I use login/password.

Comment: It works for LN too. Write an answer.

Comment: @Christian, you can put your comment as an answer it seem to work for both Exchange SMTP an Lotus SMTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i commented you can add `-credential` parameter to `send-mailmessage`  like `-credential (get-credential)` and fill it using valid  userid and password